# Angularjs loop through element

Tags: angularjs

I want to create an html structure like that: 
`<div><img src="...."><img src="...."><img src="...."><img src="...."></div>`
If I use `<div ng-repeat="image in images"><img ng-src="{{images}}"/></div`, i will get structure like: `<div><img></div> <div><img></div> <div><img></div> <div><img></div>`. 
 So, have anyway to loop img without `div` parent loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just do:

```
 <div>
     <img ng-repeat="image in images" ng-src="images">
 </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Put the `ng-repeat` on the image instead

```
<div>
  <img ng-repeat="image in images" ng-src="image"/>
</div>
```